# How does babel-loader / tsc compiler know NOT to import a package when it's being imported just for the types?

Tags: typescript, firebase, webpack, tsc

I'm currently implementing Typescript on my project.

And I've found out something curious.

You can see on the App.tsx file below that I had to `import firebase from "firebase/app"` in order to gain access to the `firebase.app.App` type.

**App.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import firebase from "firebase/app";

interface App_PROPS {
  firebase: firebase.app.App | null;
};

firebase.initializeApp({});

const App: React.FC<App_PROPS> = () => {
  return(
    <div>App</div>
  )
};

export default App;
```

And I thought that this would become a bug in my project, because since I do SSR, that import **CANNOT** happen on my server code, because `firebase/app` is not meant to be used on the server. That is why the `firebase` package is passed passed down `props`, by the way.

But for my surprise, the package is not imported at all:

When I transpile it with babel using `babel-loader` (via webpack), this is what I get:

**App.js - transpiled with `babel`**

```
var _react = _interopRequireDefault(require("react"));

// (...) SOME OTHER CODE
// I WILL NOT POST THE FULL CODE HERE
// BUT "firebase/app" WAS NOT IMPORTED
```

Also when I transpile it using `tsc src/App.tsx`

**App.js - transpiled with `tsc`**

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var react_1 = require("react");
;
var App = function () {
    return (<div>App</div>);
};
exports["default"] = App;

// "firebase/app" WAS NOT IMPORTED
```

Could anybody explain to me what is happening in this situation? I'm glad the transpilers don't import the package, but why is that?

Is it because I'm only using the package inside an `interface {}` ? So, after transpiling for typescript that interface will be gone (since it cannot exist in JS) and the package will be dropped by some `tree-shaking` algorithm?

**OBS:** I've also tried the same code, but this time calling `firebase.initializeApp()`, which is a method from the firebase package. And in this case, the `firebase/app` package is imported in the transpiled versions of the `App.tsx` file, which makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all comes down to **Does this import been use as a value? Or just Type?**

I'll explain:

Taken this for example:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
```

If you use `firebase.initializeApp()` - **you use its value**, the generated javascript from typescript compilation need to supply `initalizeApp` function and have it run in runtime - after compilation ends. This means it needs to have access to `firebase` import thus typescript compilation **doesn't cut** this import and later webpack transfer it to **__*webpack__require***.

On the other hand, if you use `firebase: firebase.app.App | null;` - **you use its type**.
You are saying to typescript compiler: "While you type safe `firebase` property, make sure its of type `firebase.app.App`." - After this type safe check, there is no longer need for anything related to firebase.

**When typescript compiles a file, it checks if it uses **only Types** from a given import. If it does, it cuts that import.**

---

SideNote:

In Typescript 3.8 `import type` keywords is introduce.

It let you define

```
import type firebase from "firebase/app";
```

Which means this import **can only be used for types**. If you'll try `firebase.initializeApp()`, the **build will fail.**
That will be classic for your scenario in case you are concern from future developers using this import as a value also.